# How to avoid mis-alignment of vertical and horizontal braces?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, underbrace

I would like both the vertical and horizontal braces to be aligned with the array. The following code obviously does not do the right thing.  Any clue?

```
\[
\text{\footnotesize \(m\) rows}
\underbrace{\left\{\begin{array}{cccc}
\bullet&\bullet&\ldots&\bullet\\
\bullet&\bullet&\ldots&\bullet\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
\bullet&\bullet&\ldots&\bullet
\end{array}\right.}_{\text{\footnotesize \(n\) columns}},
\]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) ?

Comment: What do you mean? I thought I did...

Comment: It is not possible to compile your code as it is right now. For example both answers to your question contain working code.  Please read the answers in the link above. They explain how a MWE should be written. A good MWE makes your question better - for other users with the same problem and for users that want to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a solution  with cases – and a variant for perfectionists:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\text{\footnotesize \(m\) rows}
    \begin{cases}\;
        \underbrace{%
        \begin{matrix}
        \bullet&\bullet&\ldots&\bullet\\
        \bullet&\bullet&\ldots&\bullet\\
        \vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
        \bullet&\bullet&\ldots&\bullet
        \end{matrix}
        }_{\text{\footnotesize \(n\) columns}}\vspace*{-3.6ex}
    \end{cases}
\]
\vspace{1cm}
\[
\text{\footnotesize \(m\) rows}
    \begin{cases}\;
        \raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height-0.7ex][\dimexpr\depth-3.8ex]{$\displaystyle\underbrace{%
        \begin{matrix}
        \bullet&\bullet&\ldots&\bullet\\
        \bullet&\bullet&\ldots&\bullet\\
        \vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
        \bullet&\bullet&\ldots&\bullet
        \end{matrix}
        }_{\text{\footnotesize \(n\) columns}} $}
    \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This will do more or less what you want. But there might be a better solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \underbrace{
    \begin{array}{cccc}
      \bullet & \bullet & \ldots & \bullet \\
      \bullet & \bullet & \ldots & \bullet \\
      \vdots  & \vdots  &        & \vdots  \\
      \bullet & \bullet & \ldots & \bullet
    \end{array}
    }_{n columns}
  \hspace{-1em}
  \left.
  \begin{array}{cccc}
       \\
       \\
       \\
    \,
  \end{array}
  \right\} n rows
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Even though you should still provide a minimal working example to make your question a good question.